# resultset get only current row

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Can I get only just the current row and pass it to a function, so I can do something like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> returnList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
while (result.next()) {
    Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    int hasSchedule = result.getInt("hasSchedule"); // get just one column and do some operation
    if (hasSchedule == 1) {

    }
    returnMap = DbUtility.convertResultSetToMap(result); // add columns of the of the current resultset to the map...
    returnList.add(returnMap);
}
```

I normaly have more than 10 columns in my resultsets, so I intent to write something like this to save time.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem with your code ? If you only want one row, don't loop, just get the first one..

Comment: Change `while (result.next())` into `if (result.next())`.

Comment: Just don't call next on the result set in that method and you should have only the current row.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking... Your title and first line refer to getting the current *row* and passing it to a function... then your code comment refers to getting just one *column* and your last line talks about having more than 10 *columns*. If you want to get a single row why would the number of columns matter? It's really unclear what exactly you want to do.